# Trigger hover event on another element

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mousehover

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="style/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.vidgroup .dxnb-img').addClass('hvr-buzz-out');

            $('.dxnb-item').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
                console.log('in here!!!');
                $(this).closest('.dxnb-item').find('.dxnb-img').mouseenter();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="vidgroup">
        <li class="dxnb-item">
            <a class="dxnb-link" href="#">
                <img class="dxnb-img" src="images/Video_32x32.png" alt="" />
                <span>1 - Some text in here</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dxnb-item">
            <a class="dxnb-link" href="#">
                <img class="dxnb-img" src="images/Video_32x32.png" alt="" />
                <span>1 - Some text in here</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dxnb-item">
            <a class="dxnb-link" href="#">
                <img class="dxnb-img" src="images/Video_32x32.png" alt="" />
                <span>1 - Some text in here</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The hover css being used is found [here](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

When I hover over the image, the hover effect works fine. My issue is that I would also like this hover effect to display when I hover over anything in the parent li. No matter what I do I cant seem to trigger that hover event.

I think the problem lies with this line..

```
$(this).closest('.dxnb-item').find('.dxnb-img').mouseenter();
```

I must be doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.vidgroup .dxnb-img').addClass('hvr-buzz-out');

    $('.dxnb-item').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var image = $(this).find('.dxnb-img');
        image.trigger(e.type);
    });
});
```

If it throws an error, please paste it here.

Comment: I tried...

$('.dxnb-item').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    console.log('in here!!!');
    $(this).find('.dxnb-img').mouseenter();
});

...but its giving a stack error in the console. Looks like its repeating something??? Sorry if the post formatting isnt quite right, this is my first post and getting to grips with the markup etc.